# using redsocks in ubuntu 16.04 problems with port forwarding in iptables

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

Hi i'm trying to use redsocks in ubuntu 16.04 using the same configuration that works in debian, opensuse, and older ubuntu distributions. but seems that with the ufw the iptable rules stop working and this didnt work anymore on ubuntu 16.04

**redsocks.conf**

```
base {
  log_debug = on;
  log_info = on;
  log = "/var/log/resocks.log";
  log = "syslog:daemon";
  daemon = on;
  user = redsocks;
  group = redsocks;
  redirector = iptables;
}

redsocks {

         /* `local_ip' defaults to 127.0.0.1 for security reasons,
          * use 0.0.0.0 if you want to listen on every interface.
          * `local_*' are used as port to redirect to.
          */

         local_ip = 127.0.0.1;
         local_port = 5123;

         // `ip' and `port' are IP and tcp-port of proxy-server
         ip = proxy;
         port = 3128;

         // known types: socks4, socks5, http-connect, http-relay
         type = http-relay;

         login = "user";
         password = "pass";
}

redsocks {

         /* `local_ip' defaults to 127.0.0.1 for security reasons,
          * use 0.0.0.0 if you want to listen on every interface.
          * `local_*' are used as port to redirect to.
          */

         local_ip = 127.0.0.1;
         local_port = 5124;

         // `ip' and `port' are IP and tcp-port of proxy-server
         ip = proxy;
         port = 3128;

         // known types: socks4, socks5, http-connect, http-relay
         type = http-connect;

         login = "user";
         password = "pass";
}

redsocks {

         /* `local_ip' defaults to 127.0.0.1 for security reasons,
          * use 0.0.0.0 if you want to listen on every interface.
          * `local_*' are used as port to redirect to.
          */

         local_ip = 127.0.0.1;
         local_port = 5125;

         // `ip' and `port' are IP and tcp-port of proxy-server
         ip = proxy;
         port = 3128;

         // known types: socks4, socks5, http-connect, http-relay
         type = socks5;

         login = "user";
         password = "pass";
}
```

**rules.v4**

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN

-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:5123
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:5124
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:5124
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:5124
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:5124
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5222 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:5124

COMMIT
```

Comment: Is your interface name `eth0`? By default it would not be for 16.04.

Comment: @DougSmythies Now that you tell me I see that the interface is called enp3s0, I'll try changing that

Comment: Thanks @DougSmythies that was the problem. If you want to post it as a response to give the votes